# Java EE application database architecture

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

I'm developing java EE database application(JSF) where I fill drop down menus from database. I looked for some tutorials and I find that they used the session bean to initialize these drop down values from database (using hibernate).As my application contains a lot of these is this a good strategy to fill values from database?

Is there any other approach to implement this? Is using backing bean for filling drop downs a good Idea?

Thanks all

Feras

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just load it in the constructor of an **application** scoped bean and use it to fill the dropdowns.

I would maybe add a background task to reload the data in the bean at certain intervals, e.g. daily, depending on how often the data will be updated.

Comment: But is this a good Idea to fill all it all at application startup as may be big part of them will not be used?

Comment: It's at least more efficient than doing it in a session scoped bean since you're then basically duplicating the data in Java's memory for every unique visitor.